# Getting error in XSLT 1.0 for adding multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to add namespaces in XML using XSLT 1.0. I am getting the below error in the XSLT -
ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:namespace''

Input XML -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:NAXML-POSJournal version="" xmlns:ns0="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16">
  <ns0:TransmissionHeader>
    <ns0:StoreLocationID/>
    <ns0:VendorName/>
    <ns0:VendorModelVersion/>
    <ns1:TransmissionHeaderExtension xmlns:ns1="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension" />
  </ns0:TransmissionHeader>
  <ns0:JournalReport>
    <ns0:JournalHeader>
      <ns0:ReportSequenceNumber/>
      <ns0:PrimaryReportPeriod/>
      <ns0:SecondaryReportPeriod/>
      <ns0:BeginDate/>
      <ns0:BeginTime/>
      <ns0:EndDate/>
      <ns0:EndTime/>
    </ns0:JournalHeader>
  </ns0:JournalReport>
</ns0:NAXML-POSJournal>
```

```
XSLT -
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension" xmlns:ns0="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 ns1" version="3.4">
  <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml' />

  <xsl:template match="*" priority="1" version="3.4">

    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16">
      <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />
      <xsl:namespace name="xmime" select="'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime'" />
      <xsl:namespace name="radiant" select="'http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension'" />
      <xsl:namespace name="schemaLocation" select="'http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16 NAXML-PBI34RadiantExtended.xsd'" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Output (Required) -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAXML-POSJournal xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension" xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"
  version="">
  <TransmissionHeader>
    <StoreLocationID/>
    <VendorName/>
    <VendorModelVersion/>
    <TransmissionHeaderExtension/>
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <JournalReport>
    <JournalHeader>
      <ReportSequenceNumber/>
      <PrimaryReportPeriod/>
      <SecondaryReportPeriod/>
      <BeginDate/>
      <BeginTime/>
      <EndDate/>
      <EndTime/>
    </JournalHeader>
  </JournalReport>
</NAXML-POSJournal>
```

I have tried with one more XSLT mapping which is removing all the namespaces however it should by logic should add the namespaces.

XSLT -

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | * | text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/NAXML-POSJournal">
        <NAXML-POSJournal xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"
xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
        </NAXML-POSJournal>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet
```

Comment: As you know about XSLT 2 or 3 with `xsl:namespace`, is there no way you could use Saxon 9 or 10  or 11 or XmlPrime or Saxon-JS to simply run XSLT 2 or 3 instead of 1 and that way avoid the error?

Comment: I want to run it on XSLT 1.0 only. This is the system requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the root element, then you can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <NAXML-POSJournal xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </NAXML-POSJournal>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise it gets more complicated. But your 2nd attempt suggests that you do.